# How to restrict access to a file on a server to specified IPs

Tags: linux, security, apache-2.2

I have a file on my apache server which i do not want the public to access.

I have a couple of IP addresses that will be needing the file, hence i want to grant them access to the file.

How can i go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict access to just a single file say `/var/www/filename.ext`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  <Files filename.ext>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.1.1 192.168.10.12 192.168.1.15
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

[mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html)? There are a few way to specify, check out the link it has a few examples.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.1.2.3
Allow from 192.168.1.104 192.168.1.205
```